# Неровный круг при использовании onDraw

Tags: android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Слева рисунок это круг используя onDraw и рисовал в Canvas через drawCircle.

А справа круг который создал через drawable circle.xml.

Можно ли сделать так чтобы круг слева был таким же как справа?

Если что могу код скинуть

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот так, добавить флаг к paint, с помощью которой рисуете:

```
 Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
```

Или так:

```
  paint.setAntiAlias(true);
```